# I want to mirror without merge

Tags: mirror-modifier

Is there any way to apply mirror modifier without merge the 2 objects?
I know that I can separate it later, but I need to use it in several pieces and all need to be separated at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a linked copy of your object with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and mirror it in one axis <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. As the object is linked, all changes will be applied on both objects at the same time (except modifiers).

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this way only works in edit mode. They should implement this, I think it's very simple to just add an option in the mirror modifier with merge or not merge

Comment: @franmahalem It is not simple. Modifiers are not generating objects. Even Geometry Nodes modifier doesn't add new objects into scene, but instead add instances inside the object. Such big shift in paradigm as you suggest not only hard to implement due to creating completely different workflow in modifiers, but also may affect performance and stability